# Flash Builder compiling swc and no swf

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I've got an old Flex project I have to bug fix - and Flash builder is now refusing to compile a swf. I'm getting a swc only in the output directory in run or debug.

Does anyone know why Flash Builder might do this? Any settings I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash builder will create swcs for *library* projects.  There is probably another "shell" project that depends on the project you're looking at;

However, if I assume that this was *supposed to* be a regular Flex project, and it got converted into a library by mistake, you can change it back by editing the `.project` file in the project root.  Look for the following XML element in that file:

```
<natures>
    <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.flexlibnature</nature>
    <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.actionscriptnature</nature>
</natures>
```

Change that to:

```
<natures>
    <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.flexnature</nature>
    <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.actionscriptnature</nature>
</natures>
```

Comment: Thanks @Brian - you nailed it.